# Univocity Parser - How to get row number in parsed bean

Tags: java, parsing, univocity

When using Univocity `FixedWidthParser`, how can I add the record/line number as a field in the parsed bean?

1. Is there an option where a bean property can be tagged as Record Number like:

```
   // Bean representing a record
   public class MyRecord {
  
          @RecordNumber //like this, record or line number from the context is assigned as value
          long recordNumber; 
      
          @Parsed
          String name;
         
          //other parsed fields
          }
      }
```

2. I am using a `InputValueSwitch`. Is there a way where the context can be got within the `rowProcessorSwitched()` so that I can try:

```
final BeanListProcessor<MyRecord> myProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<MyRecord>(
                    MyRecord.class);

public void rowProcessorSwitched(RowProcessor from, RowProcessor to) {
    ParsingContext context = ... //how to get this?
    long lineNumber = context.currentLine(); //if i can get this...
    if (from == myProcessor){
      (MyRecord)myProcessor.getBeans().get(0).setRecordNumber(lineNumber); //...then this should be possible
      //other switch logic
    }
}
```

Update:
Within the InputSwitch, I have tried to implement processStarted

```
   ParsingContext refToContext = null;
   
   public void processStarted(ParsingContext context) {
     refToContext = context;
     super.processStarted(context);
  }
```

and within the rowProcessorSwitched() use it like,

```
long lineNumber = refToContext.currentLine() - 1;
```

Is this a valid approach? Is it dependable - **esp, when errors are faced during parsing**.

Comment: Was going to write an answer, but I don't have one for "how to use a custom row processor." Instead, I've been setting the property during my first loop through the beans. Sadly, it seems that the library owner is no longer active; doesn't respond to support emails, doesn't respond to issues on GitHub...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't use `InputSwitch` or `InputValueSwitch`, but does produce beans with a `rowNumber` property which represents their row number.

```java
final BeanListProcessor<MyRecord> myProcessor = new BeanListProcessor(MyRecord.class) {

    public void beanProcessed(Object bean, Context context) {
        bean.setRowNumber(beans.size());  // +/- to adjust for header row(s)
        super.beanProcessed(bean, context);
    }
}
```

The only thing I have to do to trigger this is make sure this processor is assigned to the settings object of the parser, then call `parse()` on the instance of `CsvParser` to which I've assigned those settings.

```java
CsvParserSettings csvSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
csvSettings.setProcessor(myProcessor);

CsvParser csvParser = new CsvParser(csvSettings);
csvParser.parse();
```

Note that I omitted the `@Override` annotation on the inner function. For whatever reason, in my production implementation, IntelliJ says this doesn't override the super class, but tests clearly show this working. I used IntelliJ's "Generate" option to stub this method, so who knows...

Also note that my production code is in Groovy, so please excuse any syntax issues; I'm converting to Java in my head.

Comment: can you explain the answer bit ? I am getting error when using the  bean.setRowNumber(beans.size());

Comment: @KalanaMihiranga, I'm not sure what more to explain. As for the error, it depends on the error.